# xmonad startup hook not running

Tags: window-manager, xmonad, compton

I'm switching from `i3` to `xmonad` on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS and hitting a weird problem.

Upon logging in `xmonad` appears to start without a problem, but closing a window with `mod-shift-c` reveals a problem. The window closes but my display is not updated. It literally looks as though the window is still open. Another more obvious problem presents itself when dragging a window with `mod-button1`:

[image]

If I run `compton` both symptoms go away immediately. Compton (0.1~beta2+20150922) was installed from my use of `i3` and I only ever ran it for transparency. I didn't *need* it to make the window manager usable.

It's also strange that I'm experiencing this problem at all since `xmonad.hs` contains the following start-up hook:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Startup hook

-- Perform an arbitrary action each time xmonad starts or is restarted
-- with mod-q.  Used by, e.g., XMonad.Layout.PerWorkspace to initialize
-- per-workspace layout choices.
--
-- By default, do nothing.
myStartupHook = do
    spawnOnce "compton &"

------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However `compton` isn't starting (I checked the processes). I have to start it using `dmenu` or from the terminal.

`xmonad.errors` is empty so I'm unsure how to debug this further.

Comment: You should have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/342754/271180 It worked for me and provides a reasonable explanation

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know if your query is still relevant today, but I faced the same issue on ArchLinux while using XMonad and Qtile too. None of the programs in my startup script would work. It then struck me that the only change I had made here compared to my old config was that I was using the 'mate-polkit' instead of the previous 'lxsession'. And voila, when I changed my polkit back to lxsession in my 'autostart.sh' (startup script), it suddenly started working. While I can't explain the exact reason behind the occurrence, it certainly has piqued my curiosity enough that I'll try looking into it!

For more info on Polkit:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Polkit

The config I used as a reference for my config:
https://github.com/antoniosarosi/dotfiles/tree/master/.config/xmonad

Their dotfiles repo explains pretty much most of the stuff you need to get started and has some really good TWM configs, do have a look!

P.S: The configs are all for an Arch-based system. You'll have to keep that in mind if you're gonna use them for yours...

Hope this helps you, cheers!